# WNetAddConnection doesn't fail but doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

My calls to WlanConnect connects fine to the AP. But if I call WNetAddConnectionA or WNetAddConnection2A, they both return 0 (NO_ERROR), but they don't connect to the AP. What's wrong?

EDIT: // added code

```
NETRESOURCE netResource;
    netResource.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    netResource.lpLocalName = NULL;
    netResource.lpRemoteName = (char *)"\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    netResource.lpProvider = NULL;
    std::cout << WNetAddConnection2A(&netResource, "password", NULL, 
CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE); // prints 0
```

Comment: How will *we* know "*what's wrong*" if you don't provide the *code*...? It should be noted that *your usage of the function* affects it... So if you don't show us the code, then, there is no way we can help you...

Comment: Look at the [documentation of this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnectiona)... It clearly states that "*This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Other Windows-based applications should call the WNetAddConnection2 or the WNetAddConnection3 function.*"... You *shouldn't* use this function **anymore**...

Comment: But I also tried with WNetAddConnection2 and it didn't work

Comment: Look at the [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a)... Have you used `WNetAddConnection2()` properly?

Comment: I'm confused about this lpRemoteName thing. Why does it need 4 backslashes, and what exactly is it?

Comment: It is an escape sequence of `R"\\"` (Hence becomes `"\\\\"`), because one backslash is parsed as `"\\"`... Or just use raw `R"\\"`...

Comment: Yeah, but why does it need 2 backslashes anyway?

Comment: Look [here](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-please-help-define-the-double-backslash-in-windows.364835/)...

Comment: Is this error just for me or is it something wrong with the code?

Comment: I think you should look at their example I linked above...

Comment: I did, but I still can't figure out what I’m missing :/

Comment: are *lpUserName* == null is ok ? not try use exactly user name instead default ?

Comment: But I think it can be NULL if it’s not required.

Answer (score 0):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a) says, when you set CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE flag, the network resource connection should be remembered.

The operating system remembers only successful connections that redirect local devices. It does not remember connections that are unsuccessful or deviceless connections. (A deviceless connection occurs when the lpLocalName member is NULL or points to an empty string.)

Have you tried to use the proper username without NULL?

Best Regards,
Baron